# Moving the mouse to move the animation only works if I open the console

Tags: reactjs, animation, canvas, react-konva, konva

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Stage, Layer, Circle, Rect } from "react-konva";
import Konva from "konva";
import ColorPicker from "./ColorPicker";

interface Ball {
  id: number;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  radius: number;
  color: string;
  vx: number;
  vy: number;
  isDragging: boolean;
}

const BallCanvas: React.FC = () => {
  const [balls, setBalls] = useState<Ball[]>([
    {
      id: 1,
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
      radius: 20,
      color: "#ffffff",
      vx: 0,
      vy: 0,
      isDragging: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      x: 150,
      y: 100,
      radius: 30,
      color: "yellow",
      vx: 0,
      vy: 0,
      isDragging: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      x: 250,
      y: 150,
      radius: 40,
      color: "black",
      vx: 0,
      vy: 0,
      isDragging: false,
    },
  ]);
  const [color, setColor] = useState<{ background: string }>({
    background: "#fff",
  });
  const [picker, setPicker] = useState(false);
  const changePicker = () => {
    setPicker((prevst) => !prevst);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    let animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    function animate() {
      const updatedBalls = balls.map((ball) => {
        let newVx = ball.vx;
        let newVy = ball.vy;

        if (ball.x - ball.radius < 0 || ball.x + ball.radius > 500) {
          newVx *= -0.8;
        }

        if (ball.y - ball.radius < 0 || ball.y + ball.radius > 300) {
          newVy *= -0.8;
        }

        balls.forEach((otherBall) => {
          if (ball.id !== otherBall.id) {
            const dx = otherBall.x - ball.x;
            const dy = otherBall.y - ball.y;
            const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            const minDist = ball.radius + otherBall.radius;

            if (distance < minDist) {
              const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
              const targetX = ball.x + Math.cos(angle) * minDist;
              const targetY = ball.y + Math.sin(angle) * minDist;

              const ax = (targetX - otherBall.x) * 0.05;
              const ay = (targetY - otherBall.y) * 0.05;

              newVx -= ax;
              newVy -= ay;
            }
          }
        });

        ball.x += newVx;
        ball.y += newVy;

        return { ...ball, vx: newVx, vy: newVy };
      });

      setBalls(updatedBalls);
      animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
  }, [balls]);

  const handleMouseMove = (evt: Konva.KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>) => {
    const stage = evt.target.getStage();
    const mousePos = stage?.getPointerPosition();
    const updatedBalls = balls.map((ball) =>
      ball.isDragging ? { ...ball, x: mousePos!.x, y: mousePos!.y } : ball
    );
    setBalls(updatedBalls);
  };

  const handleChangeComplete = (color: any) => {
    setColor({ background: color.hex });
    const newArr = [...balls];
    const newObj = { ...newArr[0], color: color.hex };
    newArr[0] = newObj;
    setBalls(newArr);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {/* {picker && <ColorPicker handle={handleChangeComplete} color={color}/>} */}
      <Stage
        width={window.innerWidth}
        height={window.innerHeight}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onClick={changePicker}
      >
        <Layer>
          <Rect
            width={window.innerWidth}
            height={window.innerHeight}
            fill="green"
          />
          {balls.map((ball) => (
            <Circle
              key={ball.id}
              x={ball.x}
              y={ball.y}
              radius={ball.radius}
              fill={ball.color}
            />
          ))}
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </>
  );
};

export default BallCanvas;
```

I tried to change `window.height` and `window.width` in the Stage component, but it didn't work; the animation doesn't appear when I am moving the mouse.

What should I change in my code? Or maybe it's a problem in my viewport.

It only works when I open the console using <kbd>f12</kbd>.

I created my app via Vite, and installed all packages: konva, react-konva.

Comment: Can you make an online demo, like with codesadnbox or something?